# Batch Check if Git call returns authentication failed

Tags: git, batch-file

I've made a small batch file to pull a Git repository and remap the file locations.  However, if the authentication fails (enter wrong credentials) on the Git pull, the batch continues its process.

I've tried a few things:

```
git pull origin Master 
IF errorlevel 1 EXIT /B 1

git pull origin Master | FIND "Authentication failed"
IF %errorlevel% == 0 EXIT /B 1
```

Neither seem to work.  How can I check the output to see if authentication failed?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the problem but in cmd you have to avoid whitespaces in your code if they are not necessary. E.g. `%errorlevel% == 0` won't compare `%errorlevel%` to `0` but to `_0` (including the space before the digit). Same holds for `... | FIND`. You should use `...|FIND` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem but thanks for making me aware of a separate issue

Comment: probably the error is printed in the error stream . Try with `git pull origin Master 2>&1 | FIND "Authentication failed"`

Comment: Just tried that (need to escape 2^>^&1) but still doesn't work.

Comment: Regard that the syntax `if ErrorLevel 1` evaluates to _TRUE_ if `ErrorLevel` is *equal to **or** greater than* `1`; `if not ErrorLevel 1` results in _TRUE_ if `ErrorLevel` is *less than* `1` (like `0`; internal commands do not return a negative value); to do an equal-to comparison use `if %ErrorLevel% EQU 1` (see `if /?`; note that _command extensions_ are required for this to work); the `==` operator forces string comparison and should therefore not be used for the numeric `ErrorLevel` value... to quit the script with the current `ErrorLevel` you can simply state `exit /B %ErrorLevel%`...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`exit` scripting page](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php)

> The DOS online help (`HELP EXIT`) doesn't make it clear that the `/B` parameter exits the *current instance of script*, which is not necessarily the same as exiting the *current script*.
> I.e. if the script is in a `CALL`ed piece of code, the `EXIT /B` exits the `CALL`, not the script.
>
> To explain, one can use `EXIT /B 0` in a similar fashion to `GOTO:EOF` to exit (or more accurately, *return*) from a called section of code inside a script.

So in your case, it depends on how your `git pull origin master` is called. Directly in a script, or in function/other script called from the main script.

If used directly in a script, a failed `git pull origin master` (for any reason, authentication or otherwise) would trigger an `errorlevel 1` and call `EXIT /B 1`.

Answer (score -3):

As an alternative to a pure bat/Windows batch script solution, you might consider calling a bash script (interpreted by the Git for Windows bash), from your bat script: `bash -c git-xxx`

```bash
#! /bin/bash
    
if ! git pull origin master; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Actually, you can call that script `git-xxx`, for instance `git-check`, and run it with `git check` directly from your `CMD` session (no need to open a `git bash` session). As long as `git-check` is in your `%PATH%`, `git check` will execute the bash script above.

Comment: Note to others, this is still a valid answer.

Comment: Nope, it is not a valid answer for a question that specifically is for Batch.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I understand your point. I have edited the answer to make clear it is an alternative, and I have added a pure batch/bat-based answer.